# IOS Array from text field

Tags: ios, arrays, text, field

I'm building an IOS app. I want the user to input two options from a text field. One of the options will later be randomly displayed in a label. I'm thinking the text field should log the information in an NSMutableArray that I can later call on. The information only needs to be temporarily stored because it will go away after it is randomly displayed in the label.

I'm not sure how to do create this array from a text field. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not a string as that is what the user puts in the text field and what you show in a label?

Comment: Will the label be displayed in another controller?

Comment: @Wain that might be what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
int choice = rand() % 2;

NSString* result;

if (choice == 0)
    result = textField1.text;
else
    result = textField2.text;

....
label.text = result;
```

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm way new to this stuff and trying to figure it out. That helps though with figuring out how the text fields work.

Comment: @user2574058 when it is called result will randomly select the text from either the first or second text field.